# How to make sidebars extend to 50px above the footer?

Tags: jquery, html, css

On this site that i'm working on: http://cacrochester.com. Is there anyway (CSS preferred but i'll use jQuery if i have to) to make the Upcoming events, and News, Views, and Prayer Requests extend all the way down to 50px above the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the below div , abolute position to the partent div , and give bottom 0px; it will always stay in the bottom

```
#rightSidebar {
float:right;
margin:0 15px 0 0;
width:150px;
}
```

make a parent container for the rightsidebar and make the parent div position:relative
if you don't want to do all these

with jquery get the offset off footer and give rightSidebar absolute postion and 50px top from footer.

If this doesn't help , let me know we can write the offset code

```
var offsetVal = $('#div');
  this offset will have top and left properties..
  offsetVal.top
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want the sidebar to stay at the top, but to extend all the way to 50 px above the footer Your absolute div way just brought the entire right sidebar down to 50px above the footer.

Comment: @cat fish , then you can specify the height for that div right, give the required height.

Comment: it's different for every page though. Every page has a different height.

Comment: you can use the following if you really dynamically calculate the height  var docHeight = Math.max(
            $(document).height(),
            $(window).height(),
            /* For opera: */
            document.documentElement.clientHeight
        );
     var docWidth = Math.max(
            $(document).width(),
            $(window).width(),
            /* For opera: */
            document.documentElement.clientWidth

Comment: @catfish , why do you want that div to push all the way down , when you don't have content. anyway it grows if it has content.

Comment: It's what the client wanted. I did it using `var height = $('#body').height()-70;
 var height2 = $('#body').height()-190;
 $('#events').css('height', height);
 $('#newsViews').css('height', height2);` but i think it looks terrible.